# How to run two symfony projects with diferent versions (v2 & v4) on MacOs with Composser

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

Today i got a new project, its a Symfony2 API Rest that i need to migrate to Symfony4 eventually. For that reason i need to run the old project at the same time that the new one. 
I'm new dev in Symfony but i have some experience with Laravel in case that it helps...

I tried to run the Sym2 project with Sym4 version already installed in my computer but (like i expected) the execution (with the command: `symfony server:start`) returned me some errors.

I think that its posible install two versions of symfony for the different projects but i don't know how do it or what i need. Maybe running the older one on a virtual machine i can resolve my problem but i'm looking for a local solution like running `symfony2 server:start` and `symfony4 server:start`.

There are the errors that it returns:

> Warning:
>   require_once(/Users/cerocatorcemx/Dev/cqm_labs_api/web/../app/bootstrap.php.cache):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /Users/cerocatorcemx/Dev/cqm_labs_api/web/app_dev.php on line 21
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/Users/cerocatorcemx/Dev/cqm_labs_api/web/../app/bootstrap.php.cache'
>   (include_path='.:') in
>   /Users/cerocatorcemx/Dev/cqm_labs_api/web/app_dev.php on line 21

Comment: Have you tried with docker?

Comment: Back in the good ole days (i.e. S2), app/bootstrap.php.cache was generated by composer as part of the installation process.  You could just go into app_dev.php and remove the require.  The file is not really needed under php 7x.  You might need to require the autoload.php file however.  Been too long since I have fooled with S2.  Sad to say that even if you get past this, you will probably run into other issues.

Comment: @MarçalBerga i not! ill try it.:O i think docker can solve my problem!

Comment: @Cerad ill try it too, and you are right its too long time from the S2 version, it may fail :/